# i need help to shorten this code a lot preferable id like to make the month selection a function but cant due to having to call in different csv files

Tags: python

i need help to shorten this code a lot

im trying to make the month selection witch is repeating shorter or into a function preferable but cant make it work, id like to make the month selection a function but cant due to having to call in different csv files what you guys got?
csv files (https://send.tresorit.com/a#1NoM7CSW08PLTTNbtHMcHw)
password:"csvtest"

```
import pandas as pd
def year():
    print("Type '2018' to select the data of 2018")
    print("Type '2019' to select the data of 2019")
    print("Type '2020' to select the data of 2020")
    print("Type '0' to close selection")

def select_the_month_of_Etherium():
    year()
    while True:
        b=int(input("Select the year:"))
        if b == 2018:
            df8 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\seena\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\2022-11-18 20.55.00\\Project csv ETHERIUM2018"
                              ".csv")#importing a csv file
            a = int(input("Enter the month(Number Only):"))
            print("Type '0' to close selection")
            if a == 1:
                c = df8.loc[0]
                print(c)
            elif a == 2:
                c = df8.loc[1]
                print(c)
            elif a == 3:
                c = df8.loc[2]
                print(c)
            elif a == 4:
                c = df8.loc[3]
                print(c)
            elif a == 5:
                c = df8.loc[4]
                print(c)
            elif a == 6:
                c = df8.loc[5]
                print(c)
            elif a == 7:
                c = df8.loc[6]
                print(c)
            elif a == 8:
                c = df8.loc[7]
                print(c)
            elif a == 9:
                c = df8.loc[8]
                print(c)
            elif a == 10:
                c = df8.loc[9]
                print(c)
            elif a == 11:
                c = df8.loc[10]
                print(c)
            elif a == 12:
                c = df8.loc[11]
                print(c)
            else:
                print("Invalid choice")
        elif b == 2019:
            df8 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\seena\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\2022-11-18 20.55.00\\Project csv ETHERIUM Y(2).csv")#importing a csv file
            a = int(input("Enter the month(Number Only):"))
            print("Type '0' to close selection")
            if a == 1:
                c = df8.loc[0]
                print(c)
            elif a == 2:
                c = df8.loc[1]
                print(c)
            elif a == 3:
                c = df8.loc[2]
                print(c)
            elif a == 4:
                c = df8.loc[3]
                print(c)
            elif a == 5:
                c = df8.loc[4]
                print(c)
            elif a == 6:
                c = df8.loc[5]
                print(c)
            elif a == 7:
                c = df8.loc[6]
                print(c)
            elif a == 8:
                c = df8.loc[7]
                print(c)
            elif a == 9:
                c = df8.loc[8]
                print(c)
            elif a == 10:
                c = df8.loc[9]
                print(c)
            elif a == 11:
                c = df8.loc[10]
                print(c)
            elif a == 12:
                c = df8.loc[11]
                print(c)
            else:
                print("Invalid choice")
        elif b == 2020:
            df8 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\seena\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\2022-11-18 20.55.00\\Project csv ETHERIUM Y(3).csv")#importing a csv file
            a = int(input("Enter the month(Number Only):"))
            print("Type '0' to close selection")
            if a == 1:
                c = df8.loc[0]
                print(c)
            elif a == 2:
                c = df8.loc[1]
                print(c)
            elif a == 3:
                c = df8.loc[2]
                print(c)
            elif a == 4:
                c = df8.loc[3]
                print(c)
            elif a == 5:
                c = df8.loc[4]
                print(c)
            elif a == 6:
                c = df8.loc[5]
                print(c)
            elif a == 7:
                c = df8.loc[6]
                print(c)
            elif a == 8:
                c = df8.loc[7]
                print(c)
            elif a == 9:
                c = df8.loc[8]
                print(c)
            elif a == 10:
                c = df8.loc[9]
                print(c)
            elif a == 11:
                c = df8.loc[10]
                print(c)
            elif a == 12:
                c = df8.loc[11]
                print(c)
            else:
                print("Invalid choice")
        elif b == 0:
            break
        else :
            print("Invalid choice")

select_the_month_of_Etherium()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
if a in range(1,13):
    c = df8.loc[a-1]
    print(c)
else:
    print("Invalid choice")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pattern of your if statements. The value of `c` is set to an element located at a certain point in `df8`. All of your if statements check `a` and then find the location of the element using the value `a` minus 1 as the index.

Meaning that all your if statements (the ones that check if `a == 1 to 12`) can be summed to:

```
if a <= 0 or a > 12: # checks for 0 and less or greater than 12 since there aren't more than 12 months in a year
    break # output error or do what you would like
else:
    c = df8.loc[a-1]
```